# Research Guidance on Elliptic Curve Cryptography

Tags: encryption, rsa, elliptic-curves

I am a freshman who want to research elliptic curve cryptography.

There are a few questions I have:

Firstly, I am not sure about how I should narrow down the topic. Where should I focus on? Can I examine a specific application of elliptic curve cryptography? Or should I basically compare Elliptic Curve Cryptography and RSA algorithms.

Secondly, which prerequisite knowledge do I need? Also, do you suggest any foundational books on the topic?

Thank you

Comment: Broad question: you could study the math behind elliptic curves, you could look at implementing them securely (and efficiently), you could study the basic protocols (ECDH, ECDSA and friends, ECIES), you could study pairing based crypto (e.g. IBE), you could study isogeny based crypto (although, at your level, I wouldn't start there). How comfortable are you with math (e.g. abstract algebra)?  Or, is implementations more your thing?

Answer (score 4):

> Firstly, I am not sure about how I should narrow down the topic.

It is better to ask your advisor to help you for selecting a good research topic.

> Secondly, which prerequisite knowledge do I need? Also, do you suggest any foundational books on the topic?

**A roadmap for learning Elliptic Curve Cryptography:**

- **Beginner:** you can learn the basic of ECC by reading Chapter 9 of [Understanding Cryptography book](http://www.crypto-textbook.com/) and/or [some](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/10/a-relatively-easy-to-understand-primer-on-elliptic-curve-cryptography/) [good](https://www.johannes-bauer.com/compsci/ecc/) [online](https://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/17/elliptic-curve-cryptography-a-gentle-introduction/) [tutorials](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2019/10/07/elliptic-curve-cryptography-explained/) and/or by ECC workshop [schools](https://ecc2017.cs.ru.nl/school.shtml).
- **Intermediate:** for a better understanding, you can read these three books: [Elliptic Curves: Number Theory and Cryptography](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Elcw/ellipticcurves.html), [Guide to elliptic curve cryptography](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387952734) and [Handbook of elliptic and hyperelliptic curve cryptography](https://www.hyperelliptic.org/HEHCC/).
- **Advanced:** for a deep dive into the mathematics of elliptic curves, you can read [Joseph H. Silverman](https://www.math.brown.edu/johsilve/)'s books.
- **Implementation:** [Implementing Curve25519/X25519: A Tutorial on Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://martin.kleppmann.com/papers/curve25519.pdf) by Martin Kleppmann.
- **Research:** for selecting a research topic, you can read last research papers of the [Workshops on Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://eccworkshop.org/).